# How output of a sub-query can be different from the total in MongoDb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I used aggregation operation to merge two different collections on "_id". I found that there were no matching records, so I simply added one to another. Later, I queried the final collection and get these strange results.

```
db.5k_irrelavant.find({}).count();
```

11001

```
db.5k_irrelavant.find({"Language": {$eq : "English"}}).count();
```

11519

```
db.5k_irrelavant.distinct("Language");
[
    "English"
]
```

While merging, I made sure that all documents should have "Language": "English" field in them. The 3rd query clears it. The strange thing is that the 1st query that output all docs in the collection has 518 fewer documents than the count of documents from the 2nd query. How can it be possible? I could have been other way around. I can't understand the reason. Ideally, both queries should spit out same numbers. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 'WiredTiger' engine, there can be issues with `count()` result when there is a unexpected or forceful shutdown.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown